# Помогите Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, sql, php7, redbeanphp

Необходим вывод списка всех пользователей в системе, немного не понимаю, как это сделать с фреймворком `RedBeanPHP`. Буду очень благодарен. Ошибка возникает в цикле `foreach`. структура бд - таблица `user` с полями `id`, `login`, `password2`

```
    $user = R::findAll( 'user' );
    if ($user) {
        foreach ($user as $login => $id) {
            # code...
            echo 'id '.$user->id.' login '.$user->login.'<br>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: В ошибке же говориться что в переменной $user нет параметра id или login

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan в каком месте такое говорится? написано, что попытка доступа к свойству у _не объекта_, что чаще всего массива или null. в данном случае `$user` это массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ошибка говорит вам буквально *"попытка обратиться к свойству у не объекта"*. Вы в коде выбираете перечень пользователей и, очевидно, получаете массив объектов (либо массивов). Далее пытаетесь обратиться `$users->id`, что и вызывает ошибку, т.к. уже сказано. что это массив объектов.

Не читал что там возвращает RedBean, но в случае объектов:

```
 foreach($user as $u){
    echo 'id '.$u->id.' login '.$u->login.'<br>';
 }
```

в случае массивов

```
 foreach($user as $u){
    echo 'id '.$u['id'].' login '.$u['login'].'<br>';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Получайте свойства не у массива $user, а у очередного выбранного элемента этого массива

```
    $user = R::findAll( 'user' );
    if ($user) {
        foreach ($user as $u) {
            # code...
            echo 'id '.$u->id.' login '.$u->login.'<br>';
        }
    }
```